# Two containers (node and redis) connected to the same network seem not to see each other

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, docker-swarm

Node `server` and `redis` containers are defined within the same `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  backend:
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/backend
    container_name: backend
    hostname: backend
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wellerman
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/src
    build: .
    environment:
      REDIS_HOST: 'localhost'
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
    ports:
      - '3231:4000'
    depends_on:
      - redis
    links:
      - redis

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wellerman
    image: redis:latest
    command: --port 6379
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

networks:
  wellerman:
    external: true
```

The network is configured in the following way (snapshot was taken when the backend node `server` got up for a moment; `redis`, although works correctly, is not reported as connected to the network):

```json
docker network inspect wellerman
[
    {
        "Name": "wellerman",
        "Id": "xiqats19pc6gb6tvmre1thyhh",
        "Created": "2021-08-26T15:56:49.678973091Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.15.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.15.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "dd114e62bb8dffe866e1293af30cb7ad86516dfaaae5eae04b9347507b26023c": {
                "Name": "backend_backend.1.w1suc8ytt8jfxvs9syspx1uv6",
                "EndpointID": "dd114e62bb8dffe866e1293af30cb7ad86516dfaaae5eae04b9347507b26023b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:0f:25",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.15.37/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-wellerman": {
                "Name": "wellerman-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "dd114e62bb8dffe866e1293af30cb7ad86516dfaaae5eae04b9347507b26023a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:0f:26",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.15.38/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4111"
        },
        "Labels": {},
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "ba2cce29a569",
                "IP": "10.12.63.2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The node `server` terminates if doesn't have established connection with `redis` instance, and since this is persistent situation, it keeps crashing.

`Redis` seems to work as intended:

```json
docker service inspect t7znrullne5x
[
    {
        "ID": "t7krullne5xvkze8xr3znlott",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 233743
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2021-08-26T15:55:05.529166159Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2021-08-26T15:55:05.534908594Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "backend_redis",
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.stack.image": "redis:latest",
                "com.docker.stack.namespace": "backend"
            },
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "redis:latest@sha256:66ce9bc742609650afc3de7009658473ed601db4e926a5b16d239303383bacad",
                    "Labels": {
                        "com.docker.stack.namespace": "backend"
                    },
                    "Args": [
                        "--port",
                        "6379"
                    ],
                    "Hostname": "redis",
                    "Privileges": {
                        "CredentialSpec": null,
                        "SELinuxContext": null
                    },
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {},
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {},
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "arm64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "386",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "mips64le",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "ppc64le",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "s390x",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Networks": [
                    {
                        "Target": "xiqats19pc6gb6tvmre1thyhh",
                        "Aliases": [
                            "redis"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 6379,
                        "PublishedPort": 6379,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 6379,
                        "PublishedPort": 6379,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Ports": [
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 6379,
                    "PublishedPort": 6379,
                    "PublishMode": "ingress"
                }
            ],
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "iyu2r81xo9fjiyhxve36dcuxx",
                    "Addr": "10.0.0.143/24"
                },
                {
                    "NetworkID": "xiqats19pc6gb6tvmre1thyhh",
                    "Addr": "10.0.15.7/24"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

From the info above it looks that `redis` is connected with `wellerman` network (`network inspect` doesn't show it though).

Looking at the logs from node `server` I find information about `ECONNREFUSED (-111)` when trying to reach the `redis` instance.

If I replace the `REDIS_HOST` env. variable from `localhost` to `redis`, I get `ENOTFOUND (-3008)` error.

Also, setting up `127.0.0.1` or the actual IP of the host doesn't change much: the connection between these two containers seem not to exist.

What would you suggest to check or change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this thing working.

Here's what I did:

- launched redis as a separate instance:

`docker run --name redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis:latest`

- moved all environmental variables to project's `Dockerfile`, setting the redis host address as the **server's IP address**. Then built the project, tagged and launched as a service:

`docker build . -t backend:v1`

`docker service create --detach=true --name backend -p 3231:4000 backend:v1`

After a couple of seconds the whole instance was running and was ready for scaling.